# date.timezone not working with nginx

Tags: nginx, timezone, php

I've tried adding the date.timezone directive in the main php.ini file, which I've located in /etc/php.ini I've also verified it's location by using phpinfo();.

This is exactly what I added:

```
    date.timezone = "Europe/London"
```

I then restarted nginx (service nginx restart), but when I go echo phpinfo() again the timezone still states UTC which I believe is the default timezone and roundcube won't let me install until I set a timezone, any ideas?

**EDIT**
Just stopped nginx, started apache and the timezone was set correctly. So this must be nginx specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what was wrong, but I believe nGinx may have been misconfigured. Stopping the service and running Apache solved it, but that was only temporary. Just thought I'd post to let everyone know.

Answer (score 1):

What about restarting php service and not nginx after editing php.ini?

Answer (score 0):

One way that timezone works well over Nginx is to type it at the last line of the file **www.conf** [in general located at /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf ; in an example of Ubuntu installation], like so:

```
php_admin_value[date.timezone] = America/Sao_Paulo
```

Now you just reboot your Linux

Answer (score 0):

Try uncomment string `date.timezone` in `php.ini` (`/etc/php/{PHP version}/fpm/php.ini`) and set timezone value.

Example:

```
date.timezone = Asia/Vladivostok
```

Then restart nginx and php-fpm services.